# Center button in custom view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I've searched the Internet and these forums but am unable to find the answer to my problem.

I have a custom view with a WebView, which resizes to the user's screen size (simulates a maximize), with 3 buttons at the top of the custom view.

These buttons are centered, but as the view resizes they stay where they are, resulting in them no longer being centered.

How can I center a button in a custom view?

I do not need to do this every time the screen is resized, as I can just center the buttons in the method call.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Your problem is with Autosizing. So You can change Your buttons autosizing like this in *Size inspector*:

[image: autosizing sample]

After that buttons will be aligned to the top center.

Comment: this centers the button, although it does add space between them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cristian You can create new *Custom View* place all Your buttons in it. For that created *Custom View* apply Autosizing which I suggested in my answer. Now Your all buttons will move nicely without spaces between them.

Comment: all the buttons are inside a custom view with the web view. are you suggesting I separate them into 2 custom views?

Comment: @Cristian Yes, why not? This view will be transparent and will not affect anything.

Comment: no reason why not, just a noob making sure he doesn't mess up, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward answer is to get the width and height of the web view.
Since web view inherits from NSView, you can get the bounds of the view.
bounds should be a CGRect and by getting half of the width and half of the height, you can get the exact center of the view! 
Hope this helped! ^_^